# Make Cool Video Gallery Responsive

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, media-queries

i'm using this plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cool-video-gallery/) on my wordpress website to display a gallery of videos.

Now, since i want the videos look good in every mobile devices, i need to resize the size of the vídeos in different resolutions. I take a look at the code and it looks it's in this function:

```
    jwplayer('video_fancy_cvg_slide_gallery_<?php echo $galleryID.'
  _ '.$place_holder;?>').setup({
      'file': this.href,
      "autostart": "<?php echo $autoplay;?>",
      "controlbar": "<?php echo $options_player['cvgplayer_controlbar']; ?>",
      "flashplayer": "<?php echo $cool_video_gallery->plugin_url . "
      cvg - player / player.swf "; ?>",
      "volume": "<?php echo $options_player['cvgplayer_volume']; ?>",
      "width": "<?php echo $options_player['cvgplayer_width']; ?>",
      "height": "<?php echo $options_player['cvgplayer_height']; ?>",
      "mute": "<?php echo $mute; ?>",
      "stretching": "<?php echo $options_player['cvgplayer_stretching']; ?>",
      "skin": "<?php echo $cool_video_gallery->video_player_url . 'skins/' . $options_player['cvgplayer_skin'] . '-skin/' . $options_player['cvgplayer_skin']  . '.xml' ?>"

  });
```

This a problem for me since it's inside a jquery function, there's no way i can resize the videos with css media queries or can I?

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick to make the video player responsive:

In the "Video Player Settings" page, you can set the Width and Height of the Video Player.
If you leave those two inputs blank, no width and height inline styling will be added to the containing div and it will resize accordingly to the page's dimension.

If you want to make sure it is responsive, you can add a width: 100% to the containing div in your css:

```
#mediaplayer_gallery_1_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
```